# what is the sequelize query relevant to the following sql query?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
SELECT "count"(DISTINCT("displayedCandidates")) 
from 
   (SELECT unnest("displayedCandidates") "displayedCandidates" FROM  roles)
"displayedCandidates"
```

here the "displayedCandidates" column is of the type of string array which contains relevant candidateIds.What I want to query is the distinct count of displayed candidates.And this sql query is properly working.

Comment: If you put the sequelize query in question, which you have written and is not generating required query. Then it would be helpful while answering.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
return model.findAll({
  attributes: ['candidateId', 'displayedCandidates'],
   where: {
     candidateId: {
     [Op.in]: sequelize.literal('(SELECT unnest("displayedCandidates") as 
     "displayedCandidates" FROM "Roles" WHERE "candidateId" ='+ '\'' + candidateId + '\')'
  )
 }
}
})
.then((model) => {
 console.log(model);
 })
.catch((err) => {
 console.log(err);
});
```

Read the documentation, this might help you.

[Sequelize Querying](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html)